# Copyright symbol not working

Tags: html, copyright

I can't get the &copy element to work to display the copyright symbol on my website. It just shows it as plain text. Anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: It's not an element, it's an *entity*. And there is no need for that. Just write it down as is: ©. The entity for that is a thing of the distant past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `&copy;` (with a trailing semicolon)?

Comment: There it is :).

Comment: (Note: it's good karma to check the 'answer is correct' checkmark for correct answers.) Then others know that the question is answered; and the question won't clutter up the 'unanswered questions' list. Glad to help.

Comment: Sorry. It wasnt there at first or I probably just overlooked it, but I only saw the "up" arrow. Thanks for that though.